# Rotating an Area2D by 90 degrees after clicking (Godot)

Tags: c#, rotation, sprite, godot

The Godot forum for Q&A dont want to let me ask my question so here we go ^^.

Hey, so I want that when I press the right arrow button that my player (Area2D) turns 90 degrees. However, this should not happen directly but with a certain time. It should remain exactly at 0 90 180 270 360 450 ... degrees. By pressing the left button it should move -90 degrees.
I currently have the code:

```
func _process(delta):
 print($Player.rotation)
 if rotate_to > $Player.get_rotation_degrees():
   $Player.rotate((1 * delta)) ####### $Player.rotate((1 * delta) * speed)
   abc = true
 elif abc == true:
   abc = false
   $Player.set_rotation_degrees(int($Player.get_rotation_degrees())) 
 elif $Player.get_rotation_degrees() >= 360.0:
   $Player.set_rotation_degrees(0)
   rotate_to = 0
 print($Player.get_rotation_degrees())

func _input(event):
  if Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_RIGHT) and not event.is_echo():
    rotate_to += 90
```

This is how it works with the perfect turning of 90 degrees. But as soon as I want to build in the speed so that it turns faster because it is very slow, and the rectangle breaks. And it is no longer straight from the lines.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: You are welcome to Stack Overflow, but I suggest you to keep it professional and avoid foul words while you ask questions

Comment: By the way, what has C# to do with this question?

Comment: @Steve Hey. You can also code in c# in godot so i can work with that too.

Comment: Just to clarify, in your code it looks as though you want the rotation to transition smoothly i.e. 1 degree at a time until it's completed a full 90 degrees. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want smooth transition between two value is best to use Tween node. When you add Tween node as child to player node you want rotate and in player node you use this code.

```
#get child node with name Tween
onready var tween = get_node("Tween")
func _process(delta):
    #test if action is presed and tween node is not running
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right") and not tween.is_active():
        tween.interpolate_property(self,"rotation_degrees",rotation_degrees, rotation_degrees + 90,1,Tween.TRANS_LINEAR,Tween.EASE_IN)
        tween.start()
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left") and not tween.is_active():
        tween.interpolate_property(self,"rotation_degrees",rotation_degrees, rotation_degrees - 90,1,Tween.TRANS_LINEAR,Tween.EASE_IN)
        tween.start()
```

More information you can find in Godot documentation https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/classes/class_tween.html